# _wspawnl/_spawnl equivalent on Mac OS X or Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos, posix

I am just porting a code to Mac OS X which is using `_tspawnl` on Windows.

Is there anything equivalent to `_tspawnl` on Mac OS X or Linux?

Or is there any posix equivalent to `_tspawnl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fork` and `execv` system call together in the following way :

```
if (!fork()){ // create the new process 
     execl(path,  *arg, ...); // execute  the new program
}
```

The `fork` system call creates a new process, while the `execv` system call starts the execution of the application specify in path. 
For example, you can use the following function `spawn` whose argument are the name of the application to be executed and the list of its arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int spawn (char* program, char** arg_list)
{
pid_t child_pid;
/* Duplicate this process. */
child_pid = fork ();
if (child_pid != 0)
    /* This is the parent process. */
     return child_pid;
else {
    /* Now execute PROGRAM, searching for it in the path. */
     execvp (program, arg_list);
    /* The execvp function returns only if an error occurs. */
    fprintf (stderr, “an error occurred in execvp\n”);
    abort ();
    }
 }

int main ()
{
/* The argument list to pass to the “ls” command. */
   char* arg_list[] = { 
   “ls”, /* argv[0], the name of the program. */
   “-l”, 
    “/”,
    NULL /* The argument list must end with a NULL. */
  };

  spawn (“ls”, arg_list); 
  printf (“done with main program\n”);
  return 0; 
}
```

This example has been taken from the chapter 3.2.2 of this [book](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch03-processes.pdf). (Really good reference for development in Linux).

Comment: I think `fork` will spawn a child process. But, I want to launch a new process given by argument. Is `execv` sufficient for my purpose?

Comment: Yes. `Fork` creates a new process which is the copy of the parent process. When the  `execv` is called the current process image is replaced  with a new process image. This is how the linux shell runs new programs

Comment: You should note that `fork()` can return `< 0` to signify error, which isn't handled correctly by the code.  Also the argument list should be `const char *`, not `char *`.  Great book; I'd dump it if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fork()/exec()`, as already pointed out, however a closer system call is `posix_spawn()` ([manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/posix_spawn.2.html)).

It can be a bit of a pain to set-up, however, but there is some example code using it is [here](https://github.com/trojanfoe/ChessCore/blob/master/src/Process.cpp) (note that this code also provides functionality for Windows using the `CreateProcess()` API, which is probably what you should be using under Windows anyway).